# Beautiful Soup Web Scraping without Identifiers

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was assigned a task at work I am unfortunately unable to solve on my own. The goal is to scrape data from the output website of a datev database. I tried to do it using beautifulsoup, but unfortunately, the html-code of the respective website contains no identifiers like "name" "email" or "class". Instead, it looks like this:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">  
    <META http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
    <LINK href="/kasus/theme/BuKa.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <TITLE>Bundesweiter Steuerberater-Suchdienst - Suchergebnis</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY bgcolor="#ffffff"><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="550">
<tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td width="100%"><h1>Bundesweiter Steuerberater-Suchdienst - Suchergebnis</h1></td></tr>
<tr height="20"><td></td></tr>


    <tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td width="100%"><P>Ihre Suchanfrage</P></td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td width="100%">
    
    <TABLE width="458">
    
        <TR>
            <TD align="right" width="282">Ort</TD>
            <TD>&nbsp;</TD>
            <TD width="261">LOCATION</TD>
        </TR>
        
        <TR>
            <TD align="right" width="282">GENDER</TD>
            <TD></TD>
            <TD>Keine Einschr&auml;nkung</TD>
        </TR>
    
    </TABLE>

    </td></tr>
    <tr height="10"><td></td></tr>
    
        <tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td width="100%">hat 29 Ergebnisse erzielt. Davon werden nachfolgend 20 angezeigt:</td></tr>
        
        <tr height="20"><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td width="100%">
        <TABLE width="550" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left">
        

            <tr><td width="550" bgcolor="#cccccc" align="right" valign="top">
            <table border="0" width="550" height="100%">
            <tr><td colspan="4" width="550" height="4"></td></tr>
            <tr><td width="5">&nbsp;</td><td align="left" width="200">
            
                <P>Herrn<br>FIRST NAME LAST NAME<br>PROFESSION<br>ADDRESS<br>CITY POSTAL CODE<BR></P></td>
                <td width="5">&nbsp;</td><td align="left" valign="top" width="240">
                
                <P>Tel.:&nbsp;TEL NUMBER<BR>
                     
                    Fax:&nbsp;FAX NUMBER<BR>
                     
                    Mobil:&nbsp;MOBILE NUMBER<BR>
                    
                    Email:&nbsp;<a href="mailto&#x3a;info&#x40;EMAIL-ADRESS">info&#x40;norbertabele.de</a><BR>
                    
                    Zust&auml;ndige Berufskammer:<br><A href=URL CHAMBER OF COMMERCE target="_blank">CHAMBER OF COMMERCE</A><BR>
                

                
                <BR>
                &nbsp;</P>
```

My goals hereby is to extract the Data I replaced with CAPITAL Letters for Privacy Protection reasons.

As I understood it (I am a total beginner) beautifulsoup needs identifiers to orient itself on the html-file and to know which information to extract. Is this correct? Or can I make the scraping with this html structure and beautifulsoup work? Can `<P>` and `href` be used as identifiers?

Comment: https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#navigating-using-tag-names

Comment: where is your code? what u tried ?